# Using the verb "fail" when we are talking about the exam in the immediate future

Tags: word-choice

Although I've come across all of them, I think *to fail in the exam* is better. Thus, the second one is the best choice. However, may be, the last one would be as pretty good as the second.

> The exam is tommorow. You haven't practiced at all. You are going to:
>
> 1. fail in the exam.
> 2. fail with the exam.
> 3. fail the exam.
> 4. fail.
> 5. fail exam.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> You are going to fail the exam.

is the idiomatic version.

> You are going to fail.

is fine if it is understood from context what you are going to fail.

Comment: Thank you all who voted, but I don't think I'll ever understand how votes/rep work on S.E. I get 240 rep for a trivial answer with no research, while answers that quote corpora, cgel and research get 20-30 rep. Strange.8-)

Answer (score 12):

@DRF already addressed the *correct* answer. Since you didn't understand why the other answers were wrong and even *preferred* some of them, it's worth noting

> You are going to fail exam.

is wrong because *exams* are countable. You need a number, article, possessive pronoun, &c. to make it work;

> You are going to fail with the exam.

is wrong because you aren't failing alongside the exam or by using the exam;

> You are going to fail in the exam.

is wrong because, aside from being the wrong preposition, it's unnecessary. It's a little murky since examination can also refer to the act of examining or being examined, but things are *on* written tests and you pass or fail the test itself, not the paper or anything on it.

Comment: Yes, saying "to fail _in_ the exam" doesn't mean to fail the exam itself, rather it means you made an error in a part of the exam. E.g. you made a stupid mistake and so got one question wrong: you failed _in_ the exam.

Comment: Thank you for you attention to this matter. I am grateful to you for having pointed out the reasons those choices boil down to.

Comment: I agree with both answers.  That said, simple words like “with” have many meanings; “alongside” and “by using” are not the only things “with” can mean.  For example, you could *have difficulty **with** the exam*.  Similarly, while “fail in the exam” is incorrect (at least for the meaning that’s implicit in the question),  you can *fail **in** the attempt* to do something (e.g., fail in the attempt to get a college degree).

Comment: "Fail in the exam" could also mean to fail at something while in the room where the exam is taking place, such as a proctor who fails to monitor properly during an exam.